# Split a futures connection into a sink and a stream and use them in two different tasks

Tags: rust

I'm experimenting with the futures API using the `websocket` library. I have this code:

```
use futures::future::Future;
use futures::future;
use futures::sink::Sink;
use futures::stream::Stream;
use futures::sync::mpsc::channel;
use futures::sync::mpsc::{Sender, Receiver};
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

use websocket::{ClientBuilder, OwnedMessage};

pub fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();

    let handle_clone = handle.clone();

    let (send, recv): (Sender<String>, Receiver<String>) = channel(100);

    let f = ClientBuilder::new("wss://...")
        .unwrap()
        .async_connect(None, &handle_clone)
        .map_err(|e| println!("error: {:?}", e))

        .map(|(duplex, _)| duplex.split())
        .and_then(move |(sink, stream)| {

            // this task consumes the channel, writes messages to the websocket
            handle_clone.spawn(future::loop_fn(recv, |recv: Receiver<String>| {
                sink.send(OwnedMessage::Close(None))
                    .and_then(|_| future::ok(future::Loop::Break(())))
                    .map_err(|_| ())
            }));

            // the main tasks listens the socket
            future::loop_fn(stream, |stream| {
                stream
                    .into_future()
                    .and_then(|_| future::ok(future::Loop::Break(())))
                    .map_err(|_| ())
            })
        });

    loop {
        core.turn(None)
    }
}
```

After connecting to the server, I want to run "listener" and "sender" tasks without one blocking the other one. The problem is I can't use `sink` in the new task, it fails with:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/slack_conn.rs:29:17
   |
25 |         .and_then(move |(sink, stream)| {
   |                          ---- captured outer variable
...
29 |                 sink.send(OwnedMessage::Close(None))
   |                 ^^^^ cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

I could directly use `duplex` to send and receive, but that leads to worse errors.

Any ideas on how to make this work? Indeed, I'd be happy with any `futures` code that allows me to non-blockingly connect to a server and spawn two async tasks:

- one that reads from the connection and takes some action (prints to screen etc.)
- one that reads from a mpsc channel and writes to the connection

It's fine if I have to write it in a different style.

Comment: This was [cross-posted to the Users Forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/futures-question-split-connection-into-sink-stream-in-two-tasks/13156?u=shepmaster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SplitSink`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.16/futures/stream/struct.SplitSink.html) implements [`Sink`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.16/futures/sink/trait.Sink.html) which defines `send` to take ownership:

```
fn send(self, item: Self::SinkItem) -> Send<Self>
where
    Self: Sized,
```

On the other hand, [`loop_fn`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.16/futures/future/fn.loop_fn.html) requires that the closure be able to be called multiple times. These two things are fundamentally incompatible — how can you call something multiple times which requires consuming a value?

---

Here's a **completely untested** piece of code that compiles — I don't have rogue WebSocket servers lying about.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;

extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate websocket;

use futures::{Future, Stream, Sink};
use futures::sync::mpsc::channel;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

use websocket::ClientBuilder;

pub fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();

    let (send, recv) = channel(100);

    let f = ClientBuilder::new("wss://...")
        .unwrap()
        .async_connect(None, &handle)
        .from_err::<Error>()
        .map(|(duplex, _)| duplex.split())
        .and_then(|(sink, stream)| {
            let reader = stream
                .for_each(|i| {
                    println!("Read a {:?}", i);
                    Ok(())
                })
                .from_err();

            let writer = sink
               .sink_from_err()
               .send_all(recv.map_err(Error::Receiver))
               .map(|_| ());

            reader.join(writer)
        });

    drop(send); // Close the sending channel manually

    core.run(f).expect("Unable to run");
}

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum Error {
        WebSocket(err: websocket::WebSocketError) {
            from()
            description("websocket error")
            display("WebSocket error: {}", err)
            cause(err)
        }
        Receiver(err: ()) {
            description("receiver error")
            display("Receiver error")
        }
    }
}
```

The points that stuck out during implementation were:

1. *everything* has to become a `Future` eventually
2. it's *way* easier to define an error type and convert to it
3. Knowing if the `Item` and `Error` associated types were "right" was tricky. I ended up doing a lot of "type assertions" (`{ let x: &Future<Item = (), Error = ()> = &reader; }`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this in ~12 hours and let you know if it works.

Comment: Btw, your receiver no longer returns a `String`. In the original code receiver returned a `String`.

Comment: @sinan yes, it doesn't need to take a `String` because the sender can just construct an `OwnedMessage` and put that directly into the channel. That way, you can send any of the 5 possible message types.