# Rust futures -- join two futures together

Tags: rust

I have this code

```
use futures::Map;
use futures::sink::SendAll;
use futures::sink::SinkFromErr;
use futures::stream::Forward;
use futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver;
use futures::sync::mpsc::Sender;
use futures::{Future, Stream, Sink};
use std::boxed::FnBox;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use websocket::async::futures::stream::SplitSink;
use websocket::async::futures::stream::SplitStream;
use websocket::ClientBuilder;
use websocket;

pub fn main(recv: Receiver<String>, send: Sender<websocket::OwnedMessage>) -> Box<FnBox() -> () + Send> {
    Box::new(move || {
        let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
        let handle = core.handle();

        let f = ClientBuilder::new("wss://...")
            .unwrap()
            .async_connect(None, &handle)
            .from_err::<Error>()
            .map(|(duplex, _)| duplex.split())
            .and_then(|(sink, stream): (SplitSink<_>, SplitStream<_>)| {

                let writer: Map<SendAll<SinkFromErr<SplitSink<_>, _>, _>, _> =
                    sink
                    .sink_from_err()
                    .send_all(recv.map(websocket::OwnedMessage::Text).map_err(Error::Receiver))
                    .map(|_| ());

                // Trying to uncomment these lines:
                // let reader =
                //     stream
                //     .forward(send);
                //
                // reader.join(writer)

                // Comment this out:
                writer
            });

        core.run(f).expect("Unable to run");
    })
}

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum Error {
        WebSocket(err: websocket::WebSocketError) {
            from()
            description("websocket error")
            display("WebSocket error: {}", err)
            cause(err)
        }
        Receiver(err: ()) {
            description("receiver error")
            display("Receiver error")
        }
    }
}
```

I added some type annotation for clarity. This version compiles, but I want another future, that reads from the stream (`stream`) and writes to `send`. I can't make it compile and I type errors are completely incomprehensible. So my questions are:

1. How do I make the `forward()` call compile? (try to enable the commented-out code)
2. How did you come up with the code that makes this compile? In my experience, futures-heavy code is impossible to write and understand because types are too complex and type errors are incomprehensible.

Comment: You join two futures with... [`Future::join`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.16/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.join). Just like the code that you have commented out.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE], emphasis on **minimal**. For example, why is `serde_json` present but not used? Where is the **error message** that you are getting? You've already asked essentially this question and [received an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46555236/155423), so you are expected to go above and beyond to make *this question* distinct. Commenting out either `reader` or `writer` from that answer and returning the other one works.

Comment: @Shepmaster sorry, forgot to mention that the code works unless I enable the commented-out code. Updated the question.

Comment: @Shepmaster`Future::join` raises crazy errors, and that's my question. How do I make that work?

Comment: @Shepmaster made the example somewhat smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed two `map_err` calls, one for mapping websocket errors from `stream`, one for mapping sender errors from `send`:

```
pub fn main(recv: Receiver<String>, send: Sender<websocket::OwnedMessage>) -> Box<FnBox() -> () + Send> {
    Box::new(move || {
        let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
        let handle = core.handle();

        let f = ClientBuilder::new("wss://...")
            .unwrap()
            .async_connect(None, &handle)
            .from_err::<Error>()
            .map(|(duplex, _)| duplex.split())
            .and_then(|(sink, stream): (SplitSink<_>, SplitStream<_>)| {

                let writer: Map<SendAll<SinkFromErr<SplitSink<_>, _>, _>, _> =
                    sink
                    .sink_from_err()
                    .send_all(recv.map(websocket::OwnedMessage::Text).map_err(Error::Receiver))
                    .map(|_| ());

                let reader =
                    stream
                    .map_err(Error::WebSocket)
                    .forward(send.sink_map_err(Error::Sender));

                reader.join(writer)
            });

        core.run(f).expect("Unable to run");
    })
}
```